# SQL error say column from COUNT does not exisit

Tags: mysql, sql, count

```
SELECT c.review, m.category, u.username, i.item, i.item_id, m.cat_id, COUNT(rv.review_id) totalCount
FROM reviews AS c
LEFT JOIN review_vote as rv
   ON c.review_id = rv.review_id
LEFT JOIN users AS u
   ON u.user_id = c.user_id 
LEFT JOIN items AS i
   ON i.item_id = c.item_id
LEFT JOIN master_cat AS m
   ON m.cat_id = i.cat_id
WHERE LENGTH(c.review) > 50 AND m.category = 'Movies' AND totalCount > 2
GROUP BY rv.review_id
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

I get this error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'totalCount' in 'where clause'
```

I am selecting this column right away, how come it doesn't exist?

I am trying to random select a review  that is listed (or voted on 2 or more times) in in table `rv`.    Also I am not sure if I am using `GROUP BY` correctly?

Comment: You can't use the alias `totalCount` in the `WHERE` clause at that point because the aggregate has not yet been grouped and evaluated. Instead, use `HAVING totalCount > 2`

Comment: I'll add that you should be cautious when using aggregates in MySQL if you have not included all columns from the `SELECT` list in the `GROUP BY`.  Most other RDBMS don't permit that, and the results are sometimes indeterminate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With aggregate columns (like `count()`), you must use a `HAVING` clause to place a condition on them:

```
SELECT c.review, m.category, u.username, i.item, i.item_id, m.cat_id, COUNT(rv.review_id) totalCount
FROM reviews AS c
LEFT JOIN review_vote as rv
   ON c.review_id = rv.review_id
LEFT JOIN users AS u
   ON u.user_id = c.user_id 
LEFT JOIN items AS i
   ON i.item_id = c.item_id
LEFT JOIN master_cat AS m
   ON m.cat_id = i.cat_id
WHERE LENGTH(c.review) > 50 AND m.category = 'Movies'
GROUP BY rv.review_id
HAVING COUNT(rv.review_id) > 2 -- Added this line!
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Some databases (including mysql) allow you to use the column alias, eg `HAVING totalCount > 2`, but using the expression works for all databases. ie for mysql (at least), you could code it as:

```
....
GROUP BY rv.review_id
HAVING totalCouunt > 2
...
```

but it wouldn't be portable to all other databases.